# apt upgrade -y command stuck on "Preparing to unpack .../google-cloud-cli_436.0.0-0_all.deb ..." on Google Cloud

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a new VM on GCP and then try updating by running:

```
apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

But everytime. it stucks at

```
Preparing to unpack .../google-cloud-cli_436.0.0-0_all.deb ...
```

I have tried deleting the VM three times and create a new one. It always stucks at this line and then update doesn't continue.

I am running Debain 10 on E2 Micro.

[Image showing the online shell window][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGRf6.png)

Comment: E2 micro is the size of my Apple iWatch. Either wait or select a larger instance size.

Comment: I think you are right ... I changed RAM to 2GB and then it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's not a resource problem because my Ubuntu server updates with no problem and they both use the same resources as you, e2 micro with 1GB of RAM.